# Three.js - Geometry doesn't display well on the screen

Tags: html, css, canvas, three.js, html5-canvas

I want to put a Three.js geometry in my website but the canvas doesn't put it in the right place.
My goal is to display the geometry in the Intro section on the right side of the screen, but something is wrong with CSS. Maybe position isn't right in the CSS file.
You can go and see the repo on Github: https://github.com/bengabo/website-2023 and my website online: https://www.bengabo.com/

```html
    <!-- Intro section   -->
    <section id="section-one" class="intro-section">
        <div class="intro-warp">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-9 p-0">
                        <div class="intro-text">
                            <h2>Je suis Benjamin, 
                            <br />Motion designer 2D/3D
                            <br />et Creative Developer</h2>
                            <p>Je travaille pour des clients français et internationaux, aussi bien dans la communication,
                            <br />le social media, la publicité, le cinéma, l'évènementiel...
                            <br />Mes compétences acquises au fil de mes expériences me permettent de répondre à une grande variété de projets 
                            <br />et de créer des animations, du storyboard jusqu’à la conception graphique.</p>
                            <a href="mailto:ben@bengabo.com?subject=J'aime beaucoup ce que vous faites :)" target="_blank" title="ben@bengabo.com" class="sp-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"  id="section-two"></i>   Contactez-moi pour un futur projet</i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='threejs-container'></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Intro section end  -->
<canvas  class="webgl" id="bg"></canvas>
```

```css
.intro-section {
  padding: 160px 40px 100px 80px;
}

.intro-warp {
  max-width: 1800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.intro-text h2 {
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.intro-text p {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.sp-link {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #212121;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #212121;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.sp-link:hover {
  color: #ffe72d;
}

#threejs-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  z-index: -1;
  /* justify-content: right; */
  /* margin-right: 5px; */
}
```

```js
/**
 * Scene
 */
const container = document.getElementById("threejs-container");

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  30,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);
camera.position.z = 6;

// Sphere
let sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(1.1, 4),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffe72d,
    wireframe: true,
  })
);
sphere.position.x = 0.45;
sphere.position.y = 0.45;
scene.add(sphere);

/**
 * Renderer
 */
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true,
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
  let width = document.getElementById("threejs-container").clientWidth;
  let height = document.getElementById("threejs-container").clientHeight;
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});
console.log(
  "Container height: " +
    document.getElementById("threejs-container").clientHeight
);

function tick() {
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  sphere.rotation.x += 0.001;
  sphere.rotation.y += 0.001;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

tick();
```

Comment: It's a lil' bit unclear where you want that sphere to be. To the right of your `contact` link?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake with my code. I've edited and changed it.
You can see  <div id='threejs-container'></div> where the sphere should display. 
In the intro, the text is on the left of the screen and the sphere on the right.
Thanks! :)

Comment: You can go and see my website: [link](https://www.bengabo.com)
The sphere isn't well placed and the footer moved back up the screen